# Sumarizing leave_time to end_date of order (despite of the end_date of leave is greater than the end_date of order_status) - mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, sum, max, min

In mysql database i modified "leave" table:

```
+--------+---------+---------+-------------+---------+--------------------------
|ID_LEAVE|ID_WORKER| FNAME | LNAME | BEGIN_DATE         | END_DATE             | 
+--------+---------+---------+---------+------------+--------------------+------
| 1      |   4     | LEON  | SPEED |2019-03-22 07:00:00 |2019-03-23 15:00:00   | 
+--------+---------+---------+-------------+---------+--------------------------
```

"Workers Table"

```
+----------+---------+---------+
|ID_WORKER |  FNAME  | LNAME   |
+----------+---------+----------
| 4        |  LEON   |  SPEED  |
| 6        |  JACK   |  FAR    |
+----------+---------+---------+
```

"Orders" Table:

```
+----------+--------------+---------------+
|ID_ORDER  |  DESC_ORDER  | NUMBER_ORDER  |
+----------+--------------+---------------+
| 20       |  TEST        |  TEST         |
+----------+--------------+---------------+
```

"Order_status" Table:

```
+----------+---------+---------+---------------------+-------------------+------------+
| Id_status|ID_WORKER| ID_ORDER| BEGIN_DATE          | END_DATE          | ORDER_DONE |
+----------+---------+---------+----------+------------+---------+--------------------+
| 30       |   4     |    20   |2019-03-18 06:50:35  |2019-03-18 15:21:32|  NO        |
| 31       |   4     |    20   |2019-03-20 06:44:12  |2019-03-20 15:11:23|  NO        |
| 32       |   4     |    20   |2019-03-22 06:50:20  |2019-03-22 12:22:33|  YES       |
| 33       |   6     |    20   |2019-03-18 06:45:11  |2019-03-18 15:14:45|  NO        |
| 34       |   6     |    20   |2019-03-20 06:50:22  |2019-03-20 15:10:32|  NO        |
| 35       |   6     |    20   |2019-03-22 06:54:11  |2019-03-22 11:23:45|  YES       |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+
```

What i've done:

I can to sumarize "Order time" of each other workers (in order_status table) on the order including with sumarizing "leave time" from Leave table and sumarizing "Order time" + "leave time". I have selected workers (LNAME, FNAME) orders (DESC_ORDER and NUMBER_ORDER) and "TOTAL TIME" on order from each other workers correctly too. I wrote the mysql command in below:

```
SELECT workers.FNAME, 
workers.LNAME, 
order_statusAgg.NUMBER_ORDER,
order_statusAgg.DESC_ORDER, 
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(order_statusAgg.stime)) AS 'ORDER TIME', 
IFNULL(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(leaveAgg.ltime)),'00:00:00') AS 'LEAVE TIME',
ADDTIME(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(order_statusAgg.stime)), IFNULL(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(leaveAgg.ltime)), '00:00:00')) AS 'TOTAL TIME'
FROM workers
LEFT JOIN (SELECT leave.ID_WORKER, SUM((datediff(leave.BEGIN_DATE, leave.END_DATE) + 1) * (time_to_sec(time(leave.END_DATE)) - time_to_sec(time(leave.BEGIN_DATE)))) AS ltime FROM leave
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ID_WORKER, MIN(BEGIN_DATE) AS 'MIN_BEGIN_DATE', MAX(END_DATE) AS 'MAX_END_DATE' 
FROM order_status GROUP BY ID_WORKER) ordstat ON 
leave.ID_WORKER = ordstat.ID_WORKER 
WHERE leave.END_DATE <= MAX_END_DATE AND leave.BEGIN_DATE >= MIN_BEGIN_DATE GROUP BY leave.ID_WORKER) leaveAgg
ON leaveAgg.ID_WORKER = workers.ID_WORKER
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT order_status.ID_WORKER, orders.NUMBER_ORDER, orders.DESC_ORDER, 
SUM((TIME_TO_SEC(order_status.END_DATE) - TIME_TO_SEC(order_status.BEGIN_DATE))) AS stime 
FROM order_status INNER JOIN orders
ON orders.ID_ORDER = order_status.ID_ORDER
GROUP BY order_status.ID_WORKER) order_statusAgg
ON workers.ID_WORKER = order_statusAgg.ID_WORKER
WHERE order_statusAgg.NUMBER_ORDER LIKE 'TEST'
GROUP BY workers.ID_WORKER;
```

But after that something went wrong:

```
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
|  FNAME  | LNAME   |  NUMBER_ORDER | DESC_ORDER | ORDER TIME | LEAVE_TIME   | TOTAL TIME|
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
|  LEON   |  SPEED  | TEST          | TEST       | 22:30:21   |   00:00:00   |  22:30:21 |
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
|  JACK   |  FAR    | TEST          | TEST       | 21:19:18   |   00:00:00   |  21:19:18 |
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
```

why "Leave_time" of Leon Speed is set on 00:00:00 despite he had a leave time in:
from 2019-03-22 07:00:00  to 2019-03-23 15:00:00.

For me it should something different:

```
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
|  FNAME  | LNAME   |  NUMBER_ORDER | DESC_ORDER | ORDER TIME | LEAVE_TIME   | TOTAL TIME|
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
|  LEON   |  SPEED  | TEST          | TEST       | 22:30:21   |   08:00:00   |  30:30:21 |
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
|  JACK   |  FAR    | TEST          | TEST       | 21:19:18   |   00:00:00   |  21:19:18 |
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
```

because the order ended at 22-03-2019 (despite he had leave from 22-03-2019 to 23-03-2019).
Is it about that lines of code in below?

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT leave.ID_WORKER, SUM((datediff(leave.BEGIN_DATE, leave.END_DATE) + 1) * (time_to_sec(time(leave.END_DATE)) - time_to_sec(time(leave.BEGIN_DATE)))) AS ltime FROM leave
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ID_WORKER, MIN(BEGIN_DATE) AS 'MIN_BEGIN_DATE', MAX(END_DATE) AS 'MAX_END_DATE' 
FROM order_status GROUP BY ID_WORKER) ordstat ON 
leave.ID_WORKER = ordstat.ID_WORKER 
WHERE leave.END_DATE <= MAX_END_DATE AND leave.BEGIN_DATE >= MIN_BEGIN_DATE GROUP BY leave.ID_WORKER) leaveAgg
ON leaveAgg.ID_WORKER = workers.ID_WORKER
```

I need help for how to deal with. I'm not lazy guy but I'm not Mysql guru too (because i'm training for 3 weeks). Can someone please give advice or idea what should i do it? Thank you in advance for any advice.